# Run For loop in parallel in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL server procedure that will take one id and process and make some inserts and this is happening in sequential. How can I do it in parallelly?

```
WHILE (@InnerCount <= (SELECT Count(Id) FROM #MB))
        BEGIN
            SELECT @StartDate=StartDate,@EndDate=EndDate,@WeekMonthName=MonthName 
            FROM #MB Where Id=@InnerCount

            DELETE FROM facttemp 
            Where ScoreCardId=@ScoreCardId AND StartDate=@StartDate AND EndDate=@EndDate

            TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

            INSERT INTO #temp (EmployeeId,EmployeeInstanceId,UserId,ScoreCardId,ScorecardTarget,OverAllScore,Rank,MetricId,MetricName,MetricScore,MetricTarget,MetricWeightPercent,MetricBandNumber,IsQualityMetric)
            EXEC [dbo].[usp_ScoreCardPreSummaryWeeklyMonthlyData] @ScoreCardId,@StartDate,@EndDate,@AccountId,@AccountInstanceId

            INSERT INTO facttemp (
                EmployeeId,EmployeeInstanceId,UserId,ScoreCardId,ScorecardTarget,OverAllScore,Rank,
                MetricId,MetricName,MetricScore,MetricTarget,MetricWeightPercent,MetricBandNumber,IsQualityMetric,
                StartDate,EndDate,Month,Year,AccountId,AccountInstanceId)
            SELECT EmployeeId,EmployeeInstanceId,UserId,
                   ScoreCardId,ScorecardTarget,OverAllScore,Rank,
                   MetricId,MetricName,MetricScore,MetricTarget,MetricWeightPercent,MetricBandNumber,IsQualityMetric,
                   @StartDate,@EndDate,@WeekMonthName, YEAR(@StartDate),@AccountId,@AccountInstanceId
            FROM #temp  


            SET @InnerCount=@InnerCount+1
        END --End of Monthly Lop
END
```

Comment: (1) I removed inconsistent database tags.  The code looks like SQL Server, so I kept that one.  (2) Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish, please.

Comment: You don't need loops,. much less parallel loops in a database. The code is slow because it uses loops of set-based queries

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, there's probably a way to do it with a proper query. Explain the *actual* problem, not how you think the answer would look like/

Comment: There is a while loop right, In that, there is one insert statement, Inorder to see results in the final table I need to complete the loop.Is there any way to see results in final table without completing the loop

Comment: can you include execution plan?

Comment: @VeeramallaSandeep again, whatever you want to do, you don't need a loop. Especially when you deal with start schema, where a *small* table can have 1M rows. You shouldn't need snapshots and deletions either

Comment: The loop is needed because `usp_ScoreCardPreSummaryWeeklyMonthlyData` is used instead of eg a stored procedure or function. A function could be used in a normal `INSERT INTO` statement. You *shouldn't* have to generate individual snapshots one by one either - just generate *all* of them at once. If the query is slow, fix it. Fact tables are meant to make aggregate queries easier and faster after all.

Comment: If you want to aggregate lots of data, use a columnstore index. These are available in all supported versions and editions. For older SQL Server versions, use OLAP cubes

Comment: Even though function used...How can i avoid loop?

Comment: Whyd *did* you use a loop in the first place? Why use a stored procedure instead of querying the table directly? What results are you trying to return anyway?

Comment: The logic is created by someone and I was asked to implement in ETL if I can do it in parallel to reduce some time

Comment: All star schemas have a date dimension or Calendar table to make weekly, monthly, yearly calculations faster and easier. A date dimension contains one row for every date in the next eg 10 years, with extra column per month, week, year, quarter, whatever is needed for groupind and reporting. This way, calculating monthly reports is as easy as joining with the `Date` table and grouping by the `Month` column

Comment: @VeeramallaSandeep no amount of parallelization is going to fix an inherently bad design. That's not how databases work. That's definitely not how reporting or data warehouse databases work. You are looking to speed up things by 2-3 times when this loop has already slowed things by 10K times

Comment: No Other way to avoid the loops and make it run parallel?

Comment: Totally agree with @PanagiotisKanavos, try to make your query set oriented and you will see magnitudes of performance benefit

Comment: What does the stored procedure [dbo].[usp_ScoreCardPreSummaryWeeklyMonthlyData]  do

Comment: If you can't remove your logic from the stored procedure, then do the parallelization on the client and not on the server. I mean, just get your periods from #MB and launch a different script for every period. You can launch all of them at the same time, creating a new thread for on your client for every period.

Comment: what do you mean by client?

Comment: @VeeramallaSandeep The application that you use to launch your script.

Comment: change `usp_ScoreCardPreSummaryWeeklyMonthlyData` so that it reads from one temp table (now: #MB) and writes into another temp table (now: #temp) using set-based operations

Comment: @devio can you please explain what is set based operations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would do in this case is creating a temporary SQL job (msdb.dbo.sp_add_job) with this T-SQL script in step 1 (msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep) and deleting the temporary SQL job in step 2 (msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job).

That way you can execute the temporary SQL job (msdb.dbo.sp_start_job) and continu running the script while the temporary SQL job is running. You do not have to worry about the temporary SQL jobs as they all delete themselves in step 2.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.